# PYGAME Detect when object is no longer colliding with wall

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, physics, collision

I'm making a platform game which is mostly based on recreate the very first Super Mario Bros.

For now what I need is to know when the player (object) stops colliding with a wall (object).
I know when it does collide, for example when player.rect.bottom == wall.rect.top then Floor state = 1. How can I make Floor state = 0 (which would make he fall) if player is no longer colliding.

I already tried by using :

```
if player.rect.bottomleft  == wall.rect.topright or player.rect.bottomright == wall.rect.topleft:
        Floor = 1
```

That makes the player fall if it's in the corner. But if the player has an acceleration, it won't pass through this point, Floor will still be Floor = 1 and the player won't fall, he'll be afloat or flying. Thanks

Is there anyway to know when it stops colliding, which would allow me to change Floor's value?

Comment: After searching for a while, I try to combine 2 codes:
 [link](https://sivasantosh.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/using-masks-pygame/)
 [link](http://pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html)

As soon as I add  
`class wall(object):
    
    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)` 

It send me this traceback

   `wall.set_colorkey((255,255,255))
AttributeError: type object 'wall' has no attribute 'set_colorkey'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the floor each frame but make sure to do it before you move your character so that he doesn't start doing weird things like falling threw the ground and glitching out.